# How to remove an item from a collection and collection view by not re-rendering the whole list? Is it possible?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Hi I'm a bit new to backbone.js

Is there a way to remove an item (and just that item) from a collection and does not have to refresh the list. Instead only remove that item from the view and collection and no refresh/re-rendering happens the view collection. Or is it even possible?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var DateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            index: '',
            valueFrom: '',
            valueTo: '',
            status: '',
            showText: '',
            text: ''
        }
    },
});

var DateList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DateModel
});

var dateList = new DateList();

var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new DateModel(),
...
});

var DateListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: dateList,
    el: $('#date-list-container'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'add', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
                // code for rendering here...
                _.each(this.model.models, function(date){...});
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely do this by changing your event listener from `this.render` to a custom listener function that receives the model that was removed as an argument and, instead of re-rendering the entire view, simply removes the HTML element representing that model from the view. That way, you don't always have to re-render the *entire* view, which can be costly, but only alter the part that has changed.

For example, this line:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.render);
```

would be replaced with a different event handler function that received the arguments for the **remove** event:

> **remove** (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.

So you might have an event listener function such as this:

```
modelRemoved: function(model, collection, options) {
  // code to find the HTML element for 'model' and remove it from the DOM
}
```

And then use it as the event handler for **remove** events:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.modelRemoved);
```

Comment: And check out the documented [built-in events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for details about what arguments they each take

Comment: Thanks! do I have to call the `remove(model,collection,options);` inside the `modelRemoved` custom event?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusing formatting (copied from the docs), but `remove` is not an actual function. That is the type signature of the event handler function you must implement. So that is why my `modelRemoved` function example has the same parameters